# How can I send a responsive mail in node js

Tags: css, node.js, image

I am working on web development in node js and MongoDB.I have to send a responsive mail on a certain time on a day.But the problem is the mail what I have sent is responsive but without any style.I don't know why it is happened.Please anyone answer this because I badly need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not node, but the mail reader.
Best solution is to read best practices, like using table-layout, avoid a lot of CSS code, etc....
https://www.sitepoint.com/rules-best-practice-email-design-coding-practices/